# Use package name in XML

Tags: android, xml, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm using Android Studio to build my application. I would like to use `gradle` buildTypes. I add a suffix to the package name with applicationIdSuffix to modify the package name for a test build type.

```
buildTypes {       
    debug {
        runProguard false
        proguardFile 'proguard-rules.txt'
        applicationIdSuffix  '.dev'
        versionNameSuffix  '-dev'
    }
}
```

Is it possible to use this information in a xml file. My plan is to modify the account type:

```
<account-authenticator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accountType=<<PACKAGE NAME HERE ??>>
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"/>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While uou can use `${packageName}` to fill in the generated package name in the Manifest:

```
<account-authenticator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accountType="${packageName}"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"/>
```

This currently (Android Gradle 0.11) doesn't work with resource files. :-(

Instead, you must create a separate version of the resource file for each build type / variant you want with a different account type:

- src

  - debug/res/xml/authenticator.xml (with debug package name)
  - main/res/xml/authenticator.xml (with default package name)

Comment: Generally this seems to solve the problem, if I read the documentation. But gradle doesn't replace the value? Do I have to do any additional stuff?

Comment: Can I use the placeholder in the resource files as well?

Comment: From looking into this further, it appears the placeholders are currently only available for Manifest files. I've edited my answer with how you can work around that limitation for resource files.

Comment: If anyone later sees this topic, someone has already requested this feature: [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=71365&thanks=71365&ts=1402601291)

Comment: You don't need to duplicate the whole (xml) resource, you can instead define two `values/strings.xml` in the debug and main resources and give a different string value there and then only reference `accountType="@string/packageName"`.

Answer (score 34):

Here's another temporary workaround until the Android Gradle plugin gets [support for placeholders in resource files](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=71365).

You can dynamically create a String resource via Gradle in the `defaultConfig` and/or `buildTypes` and/or `productFlavors` closure:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.foo.bar'
        resValue 'string', 'package_name', applicationId
    }
}
```

You can then reference it in your `authenticator.xml` file just like you do for the label:

```
<account-authenticator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accountType="@string/package_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"/>
```

Comment: Nice one, I made it even simpler in this gist (as the `applicationId` might change) https://gist.github.com/Takhion/74b67cb518e90faf2708

Comment: @Takhion Where do you place that code in the project?

Comment: EDIT: You can just place it in the build.gradle of the app. Because the toLowerCase, my resource files could not be found

Comment: @Cheshire place that snippet in the `build.gradle` of your Android project :)

Answer (score 10):

On top of **jenzz**'s answer, i had to do this, since my case is just like as question, i add `applicationIdSuffix` for debug version of app.

```
android {
    ...

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "..."
        ...
    }
    ....

    buildTypes {
        release {
            ...
            resValue 'string', 'application_id', android.defaultConfig.applicationId
        }

        debug {
            ...
            applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
            resValue 'string', 'application_id', android.defaultConfig.applicationId + applicationIdSuffix
        } 
}
```

Then in any *xml resource*, i can get application Id as like this: `@string/application_id`

Comment: This seems to not work with e.g. `android:targetPackage` in the shortcuts xml since it expects an actual string and not a reference.

Comment: Worked for me for Preference intent android:targetPackage. Nice answer for the idSuffix!!!

Answer (score 2):

I'm using `${applicationId}` like follow for example:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.abnerescocio.embaixadordorei.presentation">

    ...

    <application
    ... 
    >

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.android.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>
        </provider>

    ...

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: This only works in the Manifest, not in other XML files.

Answer (score 0):

I've just created a gradle plugin for this: [com.inutilfutil.android-resource-placeholder](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.inutilfutil.android-resource-placeholder)

Just include it and placeholders will be replaced on all XML resources

Comment: Could you please add a code example of how to use the plugin and get it to replace the placeholders?

Comment: Nvm, used the same ```manifestPlaceholders``` in build types and flavors for various combinations and it replaced the placeholders correctly. Thanks.