# Using variables in Android shortcuts feature xml?

Tags: android, shortcut

I am playing around with Android's [shortcut](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts.html) feature and I have the following xml:

```
<shortcuts
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <shortcut
        android:shortcutId="some_id"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_icon"
        android:shortcutShortLabel="@string/short_label"
        android:shortcutLongLabel="@string/long_label"
        tools:targetApi="n_mr1">
        <intent
            android:action="android.intent.action.MAIN"
            android:targetPackage="my.package"
            android:targetClass="my.package.MainActivity" />
    </shortcut>
</shortcuts>
```

Having it like this, it works without a problem.

Can I use variables in the shortcuts xml file as I can do for example in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
```

So I would like to have the same behavior with shortcuts, but somehow it doesn't work:

```
<intent
    android:action="android.intent.action.MAIN"
    android:targetPackage="${applicationId}"
    android:targetClass="my.package.MainActivity" />
```

Do you have any idea how to use variables here?

The reason I would like to do this is that we have multiple environments with different package names: `my.package.test`, `my.package.debug`, `my.package.hotfix`, etc...

Comment: any solution without using 3th part libraries as commented below?

Comment: Looks like an old but dead feature request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-122253

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24356595/use-package-name-in-xml

Comment: I tried the manifestPlaceholders via build.gradle but even that fails to work.

Answer (score 4):

I created a plugin which make it possible to use manifestPlaceholders in resources and is usable with version 3.0.0 of the android gradle plugin

https://github.com/timfreiheit/ResourcePlaceholdersPlugin

src/main/res/shortcuts.xml:

```
<shortcuts xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <shortcut ...>

        <intent
            android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
            android:targetClass="com.test.MainActivity"
            android:targetPackage="${applicationId}"/>
    </shortcut>
</shortcuts>
```

Comment: Great plugin, saves a lot of work. Thanks. Hopefully Android will be able to replace place holders in resources one day. Till then, this is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

> Do you have any idea how to use variables here?

That is not supported at the present time. Manifest placeholders are used in the manifest merger process for manifests. There is no equivalent for resources.

The simplest solutions would revolve around setting up dedicated build types or product flavors. In your case, it would seem like build types are the appropriate model. Having a dedicated shortcuts XML resource per build type would work. In theory, you could have dedicated string resources per build type with the application ID (e.g., `app_id`, set up using `resValue` in Gradle), then use `android:targetPackage="@string/app_id"` in a single shortcuts XML resource. However, I am uncertain if we can use string resources there.

Comment: Using string resources was a good idea, however it doesn't work either. The only solution is to have multiple resource files per build type as for now, but at least that is working. I wanted to avoid it, but it seems I cannot at the moment.

Comment: @ktamas: In principle, it is possible to create a Gradle plugin that would perform manifest merger-style variable replacements that result in resources. It could take something like `res-template/xml/shortcut.xml` and generate the correct XML resources in `build/generated/` based upon build variants and supplied placeholders. I don't know that anyone has built this, and it would be overkill for you to roll one yourself just for this situation.

Comment: Using string resource does not work, it will print the address not the value for that address.